# Como calcular a média de alunos e mostrar em porcentagem?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Estou tentando criar um algoritmo em C# conforme esta no exercicios, no visual studio, para calcular varias médias de alunos e mostrar alunos acima da media em porcentagem,tentei fazer o algoritmo em C#,mas em porcentagem não sei como se faz,tentei um codigo mas esta faltando colocar a porcentagem,[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]alguém poderia me ajudar?

```
class Colegio
{
 static void Main(){
    double nota1,nota2,nota3,nota4,nota5,nota6,nota7,nota8,nota9;
    double media;

    Console.Writeline("Digite a primeira nota":);
    nota1=Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.Writeline("Digite a segunda nota":);
    nota2=Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.Writeline("Digite a terceira nota":);
    nota3=Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.Writeline("Digite a quarta nota":);
    nota4=Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.Writeline("Digite a quinta nota":);
    nota5=Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.Writeline("Digite a sexta nota":);
    nota6=Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.Writeline("Digite a setima nota":);
    nota7=Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.Writeline("Digite a oitava nota":);
    nota8=Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.Writeline("Digite a nona nota":);
    nota9=Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

    media = ( nota1 + nota2 + nota3 + nota4 + nota5 + nota6 + nota7 + nota8 + nota9) / 9;

   if(media >=70)
   {
     Console.Writeline("Acima da média");
   }
   else
   {
     Console.WriteLine("abaixo da média");
   }

   Console.ReadKey();
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: 40% = 0.4, por exemplo 40% de 100, tu faz resultado = 0.4*100, resultado = 40

Comment: @FourZeroFive desculpa pela pergunta,mas onde coloco este código?

Comment: Sua interpretação do problema está errada. Voê está calculando a média das notas, quando deve calcular a quantidade de alunos com nota > 70. Na amostra {50, 50, 70, 80, 100}, tem 2 alunos com nota > 70 e são 5 alunos, entao voce teria que fazer 2/5 = 0.4 ou 40% . E os alunos abaixo seria 3/5= 0.6 ou 60%

Comment: @BernardoLopes desculpa bernardo,fiquei perdida agora, como ficaria esse codigo dentro do meu codigo, teria como vc escrevere esse algoritmo?

Comment: @BernardoLopes entendi agora o que vc quis dizer, o problema quer saber apenas quem esta acima > do 70, e teria como vc escrever o codigo pra mim ?

Comment: Incrementa uma variavel para contar quantos  alunos acima da media. e divide pelo total de alunos. Precisaria de um loop percorrendo cada nota e verificando ```if(nota >70){tAlunoAcima ++}```e no final so divide ```tAlunoAcima/total```

Comment: Se entendi corretamente, a média  70 seria uma amostraapenas e a leitura do problema seria:
>>  media = (nota1 + nota2 + nota3 + nota4 + nota5 + nota6 + nota7 + nota8 + nota9) / 9

Ou seja total de alunos é 9.
Após ter a nota média, precisará resgatar a notas (nota1, nota2 etc) que sejam/estejam acima dessa media, somar os alunos que estão acima da média e aí sim calcular a porcentagem com a seguinte conta: >>  porcentagem = totalAlunosAcimaDaMedia /  totalDeNotasAlunos;

Comment: @BernardoLopes vou tentar aqui.

Comment: Não tenho muita familiaridade com C#.

Answer (score 1):

```
  class Colegio

   {
    static void Main(string[] args)
           {
        //voce nao sabe a quantia de notas que serao dadas então deve informar antes para criar um vetor para elas
        Console.WriteLine("Quantidade de notas a serem inseridas: ");
        int quantidade = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int i = 0;
        double acimaDaMedia=0;
        double media=0;
        double mediaTotal, porcentagem;
        double[] notas = new double[quantidade];
        //laço para informar as notas
        while (i != quantidade)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Digite a " +(i+1)+"ª nota");
            notas[i] = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            i++;
        }
        //laço para somar as notas
        for(int x=0; x< notas.Length; x++)
        {
            media += notas[x];
        }
          //equacao para descobrir o valor da media
        mediaTotal = media / quantidade;
        //laço para descobrir quantos estão acima da media
        for(int x = 0; x < notas.Length; x++) {
            if (notas[x] > mediaTotal)
            {
                acimaDaMedia++;
            }
        }
       //equaçao para saber a porcentagem daqueles que estao acima da media
        porcentagem = (acimaDaMedia* 100) /quantidade;
        Console.WriteLine("a media é: "+ mediaTotal.ToString("F1"));
        Console.WriteLine("a porcentagem é: " + porcentagem.ToString("F3")+"%");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: obrigada, vou estudar esse código

Comment: Ok, qualquer duvida ou dificuldade sobre o código, só comentar aqui. Bom estudo.

Comment: Se essa solução lhe ajudou, marque essa resposta como aceita para que ela seja concluída. Abraço!

Answer (score 0):

```
class Colegio
{
static void Main(){
    double nota1,nota2,nota3,nota4,nota5;
    int totalAluno = 5;
    int tAcima = 0;
    //double[] notas = new double[5];
    int[ ] notas = new int[]{ 50, 50, 70, 80, 100 };

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
      if(notas[i] > 70){
        tAcima++;
      }
    }
    
    double perAcima = (double) (tAcima/totalAluno);
    double pAcima = perAcima * 100;
    
    double perAbaixo = (double) ( (totalAluno- tAcima) / totalAluno );
    double pAbaixo = perAbaixo * 100;
  }
}
```

Nao deu pra colocar Console.Write. nao tenho c# instalado

Comment: @Bernado Lopes obrigada mesmo assim. =)

Comment: @Bernado Lopes sou nova em programação em C# e java caso vc esteja programando algum projeto com outros grupos de programadores, me inclue,meu foco no momento é aprender o máximo de programação.